# How to display the name attributes of all the of the meta tags in the document?

Tags: javascript

I need to display the name attributes of all the meta tags in the document.

I tried to use:

```
var attrs = document.getElementsByTagName("meta").attributes;
```

but it's not working.

Comment: What made you think that would work? `getElementsByTagName` returns an array-like object where each index item is one of the elements.

Comment: I dont know. Im just learning dom for javascript ;) but I already make it work with simple loop

Answer (score 2):

You could try a simple `for` loop:

```
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")
var names = []
for (var i = 0; i < metas.length; i ++) {
    names.push(metas[i].name)
}
```